# How do I get stack my web page content in to 2 columns and be consistent on page sizes

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need my web page to stack in two column, this is what it is doing now:

[image]

Here is my code so far...

**This is my AddCustomer.cshtml:**

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData      

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account Screen";
 }

<h2>AccountScreen</h2>

<div>
   <fieldset class="leftdiv">
    <legend>customer info</legend>
    <div>   
      @Html.Partial("CustomerInfoPartialView")
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="rightdiv">  
    <legend>balance</legend>
    <div>
      @Html.Partial("BalancePartialView")
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div> 
<div>
   <fieldset class="leftdiv">
    <legend>customer info</legend>
    <div>   
      @Html.Partial("DeliveryPartialView")
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="rightdiv">  
    <legend>balance</legend>
    <div>
      @Html.Partial("SomeOtherPartialView")
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**This is my BalancePartialView.cshtml:**

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData

          <div  class="leftdiv">
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 30:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 60:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 90:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 120:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Current:</label>
          </div>

          <div class="rightdiv">
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Over30)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Over60)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Over90)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Over120)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentBalance)</label>
          </div>
```

**This is the CustomerInfoPartialView:**

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData


          <div  class="leftdiv">
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Account Number:</label>            
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Name:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Care of:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Mailing Address:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">City/St/Zip:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Delivery Address:</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Delivery City:</label>
          </div>

          <div class="rightdiv">
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Branch) - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CareOf)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City),&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.State)&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ZipCode)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeliveryStreet)</label>
            <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeliveryCity)</label>
          </div>
```

**And finally, my css:**

```
.sizedCustomerlabel 
{
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  padding: .1em;
  text-align: right;
}

.sizedCustomerDataRightlabel 
{
  display: block;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: left; 
  padding: .1em;
}

.sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel 
{
  display: block;
  width: 20em;
  text-align: left; 
  padding: .1em;
}

.SmallRedlabel 
{
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: .1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: blue;
}

.rightdiv {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    text-align:left
}
.leftdiv {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    text-align:left
}

.bigarealabel {
    margin:250px 50px;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to acheive this better than what I am doing? They way I'd doing it is crap. I feel like I'm trying to create a clay bowl out of stone lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your `AddCustomer.cshtml` to this

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData      

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account Screen";
}

<h2>AccountScreen</h2>

<div>
    <div class="leftdiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>customer info</legend>

            <div>
                @Html.Partial("CustomerInfoPartialView")
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>balance</legend>

            <div>
                @Html.Partial("BalancePartialView")
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="rightdiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>customer info</legend>

            <div>
                @Html.Partial("DeliveryPartialView")
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>balance</legend>

            <div>
                @Html.Partial("SomeOtherPartialView")
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html), a framework for responsive design. The page is adjusted to the size of the window no matter the device.

If you want to do it by yourself, use 2 `div` with CSS `position: absolute;` and one `left: 0px;` and the other `right: 0px;`.